# GPG passphrase change ineffective

Tags: gpg, gpg-agent

I've changed a passphrase for a secret key:

```
$ gpg --edit-key <PUBKEY_ID>
passwd
<old_passphrase>
<new_passphrase>
<new_passphrase>
save
```

Reloaded using `gpgconf --reload`, however the old password still is in use when trying to decrypt.

`$ gpg2 -d somefile.gpg` where this file is encrypted with a public subkey of the one I changed the passphrase of. It prompts me for the passphrase and only accepts **`<old_passphrase>`**.

However, when I run `$ gpg --edit-key <PUBKEY_ID>` and `passwd` again, it **does** require me to use **`<new_passphrase>`** to unlock the key.

What is going wrong here?

---

Running KDE Neon 5.8 (Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial based)

```
$ gpgconf --list-components
gpg:GPG for OpenPGP:/usr/bin/gpg2
gpg-agent:GPG Agent:/usr/bin/gpg-agent
scdaemon:Smartcard Daemon:/usr/lib/gnupg2/scdaemon
gpgsm:GPG for S/MIME:/usr/bin/gpgsm
dirmngr:Key Acquirer:/usr/bin/dirmngr
pinentry:PIN and Passphrase Entry:/usr/bin/pinentry
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the command that you use to change the password (in your question) is `gpg` while the command that you use to decrypt is `gpg2`.

These two commands belong to two separate installations of GnuPG. One is probably GnuPG 1.4.x (or at least older than 2.1) and the other may be GnuPG 2.1.x.  These two versions of GnuPG manages the keys in separate ways.

To change the password for `gpg2`, use `gpg2 --edit-key` (rather than `gpg --edit-key`)

From "[What’s new in GnuPG 2.1](https://www.gnupg.org/faq/whats-new-in-2.1.html#nosecring)":

> To ease the migration to the no-secring method, `gpg` detects the presence of a `secring.gpg` and converts the keys on-the-fly to the the key store of `gpg-agent` (this is the `private-keys-v1.d` directory below the GnuPG home directory (`~/.gnupg`)). This is done only once and an existing `secring.gpg` is then not anymore touched by `gpg`. This allows co-existence of older GnuPG versions with GnuPG 2.1. **However, any change to the private keys using the new `gpg` will not show up when using pre-2.1 versions of GnuPG and vice versa.**

(Note that `gpg` in the text above refers to the `gpg2` executable of GnuPG 2.1)